# When do Census Tracts get their boundaries adjusted?

Tags: us-census, census

I'm curious as to when the 2020 US Census Census Tract geometries actually get adjusted to account for any changes. I know they're semi-permanent, but that can indeed change from year to year.

We have some boundaries that are defined by grouped Census Tracts, and wondering what the earliest year is I might possibly be able to reconfirm/adjust our boundaries.

Comment: have you contacted census.gov and asked them?

Answer (score 1):

The American Community Survey public use data had the 2000 delineations (public use microdata areas, PUMA) in the 2010 and 2011 data releases. The 2012 ACS data were released with the 2010 geographies. The delay may have had to do with the planning of the 2011 data collection being done in early 2010 when the new data were not available, actually. The more stringent release date for the geographic products is a year from the census day, see https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial-census/2020-census/planning-management/planning-docs/RDP-detailed-op-plan.html, although that data may still only be distributed to the states / through the official channels.